How to use ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly?
Solution structure:

Domain

Entities


Data

Context

MyDbContext.cs


Maps

20+ configs




MyApp – startup project

Currently I'm applying configs like this:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MyEntity1());
    // etc. 20+ times
}

I tried using ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly with typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly GetType().Assembly Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() arguments, but it didn't work. When launched, it gives a mapping error as if I had not specified the appropriate files.

There is a mapping between the c# classes/properties and the tables/fields of the database.  The error indicates the mapping is not correct.  Use Migration to update the mapping and try again.

@jdweng But when I connect each config separately using ApplyConfiguration, everything works fine. Migration is not allowed here because Database First.

Database first no longer is an option.  You must run migration on your c# model and either use Create or Update.  Your code will not work if the model is not properly mapped to the database.
